# keras: Change dimension of Image object to feed into an ANN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to learn Neural Networks!
I'm trying to compare Convolutional Neural Network and Dense Neural Network on OCR of 100 x 100 pixel character.
I'm modifying David Shapiro's code on OCR to create an ANN to compare to his CNN model. https://github.com/daveshap/ocr_svc

His random character image generator generates 100 x 100 (I modified it from 32x32 to 100x100 to really see the effect of overfitting - if it happens)

```
def make_random_image(font_file, c, i):
    paper = 255 #white
    ink = random.randint(0, 90)
    font_size = random.randint(min_font, max_font)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_dir + font_file, font_size)
    string = c 
    canvas = Image.new('RGBA', (base_size, base_size), (paper, paper, paper))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
    w, h = draw.textsize(text=string, font=font)
    w = round((base_size - w) / 2)
    h = round((base_size - h) / 2)
    draw.text((w, h), string, (ink, ink, ink), font=font)
    ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
    canvas = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(canvas))
    # save file
    filename = font_file.lower().replace('.ttf', '') + '_%s_%s_%s.png' % (charset.index(c), c, i)
    canvas.save(save_dir + filename)
    canvas = np.asarray(canvas)
    canvas = cv2.cvtColor(canvas, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    return canvas
```

Then using Keras front-end and Tensorflow backend, I (atleast wanted to ) create an ANN:

```
def instantiate_model():
    print('COMPILING MODEL')
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10000,input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
    ['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

What should be the input shape and how can I change the 100x100 Image to the appropriate input shape? Also, any suggestion on the shape of this ANN? I'm expecting it to fail compared to CNN from what I read.

I feel like the input shape should be 1 dimension 10,000 but I am not sure.

EDIT=========
David Shapiro prepares his training set by:

```
def prepare_datasets(samples):
    random.shuffle(samples)
    training_set = samples[:round(len(samples) / 10 * 9)]
    training_data = [i[0] for i in training_set]
    training_data = np.asarray(training_data).astype('float32')
    training_data = np.expand_dims(training_data, axis=3)
    training_data /= 255
    training_labels = [i[1] for i in training_set]
    training_labels = np.asarray(training_labels)
    training_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(training_labels, num_classes)
    print('TRAINING DATA SHAPE', training_data.shape)
    print('TRAINING LABELS SHAPE', training_labels.shape
    return training_data, training_labels
```

The result of his method is:
TRAINING DATA SHAPE (9360, 100, 100, 1)
TRAINING LABELS SHAPE (9360, 26)

which then is fed to `model.fit(training_data, training_labels, batch_size=batch, epochs=epoch, verbose=1)`
Maybe changing the dimension could be done from here! I'm still learning how to use numpy so I dont know all the methods...
Thank you for even reading this long post!

Comment: Use [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method from numpy: `training_data = np.reshape(training_data, (-1, 10000))`. The `-1` there means that the size of first axis (i.e. number of training samples) is automatically inferred.

Comment: Plus, you have too much units in the first Dense layer. It is highly prone to overfitting. Reduce it to something like 1000 or even lower. Further, don't forget to pass the `input_dim=10000` argument to the first Dense layer. It means each training sample is a vector of length 10000.

Comment: @today Thanks for the reply!
So should the code look more like: `model.add(Dense(1000,input_shape=(10000,1), activation='relu'))`
and delete `training_data = np.expand_dims(training_data, axis=3)` to `training_data = np.reshape(training_data, (-1, 10000))`? I did the np.reshape and it resulted me shape `TRAINING DATA SHAPE (9360, 10000)`.

Comment: That's correct. However, the input shape argument must be `(10000,)`.

Comment: @today changing the input_shape to (10000,1) gave me `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_58_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (9360, 10000)` What went wrong here... ;_;

Comment: @today Saw your edit!  It's working! :) I'm gonna have fun not sleeping tonight to compare the results between CNN and ANN yay :D

Comment: Since the training data has two dimensions you need to pass the input shape as `(10000,)`, i.e. the third axis with value of `1` is redundant and wrong. Have fun :)